# Where are "the kernel stack", "Frames for C run-time startup functions", and "Frame for main()" in the memory layout of a program?

Tags: linux, process, virtual-memory

From The Linux Programming Interface:

[image]

1. Where is the kernel stack (mentioned in the quote below) in the above diagram?

   Is it the top part "Kernel (mapped into process virtual memory, but no accessilto program)" in the above diagram?

   > the  term  **user  stack**  is  used  to  distinguish the  stack  we  describe  here
   >   from the kernel stack. **The kernel stack** is a per-process memory region maintained
   >   in kernel memory that is used as the stack for execution of the functions called
   >   internally during the execution of a system call. (The kernel can’t employ the user
   >   stack for this purpose since it resides in unprotected user memory.)
2. Where are "Frames for C run-time startup functions" and "Frame for main()" (mentioned from the diagram below) in the above diagram?

   Is  "argv, environ" in the above diagram  "Frames for C run-time startup functions", "Frame for main()", or part of either?

   [image]
3. What is the lowest segment between 0x00000000 and 0x08048000 used for?

Thanks.

Comment: That is not a complete diagram, bear in mind.  auxv is missing; application-space memory for the stacks of other threads is missing; and heap allocated with `mmap` rather than `sbrk` is missing.

Comment: can you show me the complete diagram? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There is not *a* kernel stack. For each thread, there is a memory region that is used as stack space when the process makes a system call. There are also separate "interrupt stacks", one per CPU, which are used by the interrupt handler. These memory areas reside in the kernel address space (above `0xc0000000` in your figure.
2. The stack frames (C runtime frames, the frame for main, etc.) are part of the stack. The process arguments (`argv`) and the environment are separate areas, and are not part of the stack.
3. The area between `0x0` and `0x08048000` (about 128 MB) is not used for anything. Originally, the i386 System V ABI reserved this area for the stack, but Linux does things differently. Leaving the area unused does not waste RAM, only address space, because the area is not mapped. Note that this information is almost totally obsolete by now, since it describes how things are done on the 32-bit x86 architecture. 32-bit only x86 machines are hard to find today, and distributions are phasing out support for them.

Comment: Thanks. In "There is not a kernel stack" and "These memory areas reside in the kernel address space (above 0xc0000000 in your figure", (1) do you mean the kernel stack for the process by "These memory areas"? (2)  do you mean the kernel stack for the process is the area named "Kernel (mapped into process virtual memory, but no accessilto program)" above 0xc0000000 in the figure?

Comment: For each process (actually thread), there exists a 8 kB memory region that is used for the kernel mode stack for the thread. The stack pointer is switched to point to this region when the thread does a system call. These per-thread memory regions reside within the address space reserved for the kernel, `0xc0000000` to `0xffffffff`. This area of course contains a lot of other things; the kernel code for a start.

Comment: @sourcejedi Ok, this is debatable. On the one hand, the program stack contains "return addresses, parameters, and local variables of the function being executed." The environment strings don't fall into this category. On the other hand, the environment, the program arguments and the program stack are all contained in the same memory region.

Comment: Sorry, I read too quickly, I didn't even notice the diagram showed envp and argv.  And the debatable part was not really part of the question.  I tend to think in terms of the stack memory region (and I don't think about what a stack frame is very often).

Answer (score 2):

cited from [csapp 3rd](https://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/) chapter 9:

[image]

> Other regions of kernel virtual memory contain data that differ for each process. Examples include page tables, the stack that the kernel uses when it is executing code in the context of the process, and various data structures that keep track of the current organization of the virtual address space.

I believe there's kernel stack for each process. At least for executing system calls, which might call kernel internal functions that need to store data with supervisor privilege. Also for kernel interrupt handlers.

related [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911841/kernel-stack-and-user-space-stack)

> 4. Does each process have its own kernel stack?
>
> Not just each process - each thread has its own kernel stack (and, in fact, its own user stack as well). Remember the only difference between processes and threads (to Linux) is the fact that multiple threads can share an address space (forming a process).